# Retrieve data from database - how?

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my database table I have two columns: `pagename` and `pageinfo`. I want  to retrieve data when I pass in `pagename`. I use code which I got from Stackoverflow today but some issue in code throws an error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.)

This is the code:

```
public string GetPageInfo(string filenames)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=.;Integrated Security=True");

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select pageinfo from T_Pages where pagename=@filenames", con);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filenames", filenames);

    // int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        return reader["pageinfo"].ToString(); ;
    }

    // return string GetPageInfo;
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2):

This is because of this:

```
return reader["pageinfo"].ToString();
```

if *reader["pageinfo"]* is null, then *ToString()* will throw an exception.

Replace above line with this:

```
if(reader["pageinfo"] != null)
{
   return reader["pageinfo"].ToString();
}
else
{
   return "";
}
```

Or using [Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
return reader["pageinfo"]?.ToString();
```

**EDIT**

You also need to add *Read()* before return:

```
reader.Read();
return reader["pageinfo"]?.ToString();
```

Comment: but pageinfo column is not null

Comment: i try this code but now this error is shown

 "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

Comment: now no error is shown but how i know the value in pageinfo.means how can i alert it or display it

Comment: @lekshminair display where? You asked how to retrieve data from database. GetPageInfo() will return the result and it's up to you where you will display it.

Comment: ya but the value getting is null